# How to encode an object that contains an attributed string to Data?

Tags: swift, encoding, nsdata, decoding, nsdocument

I have an `NSDocument` subclass that contains a property of type `NSAttributedString` (among others). In order to enable persistence I need to override the following two methods:

```
override func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data {
    // Insert code here to write your document to data of the specified type, throwing an error in case of failure.
    // TO BE IMPLEMENTED...
}

override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {
    // Insert code here to read your document from the given data of the specified type, throwing an error in case of failure.
    // TO BE IMPLEMENTED...
}
```

**How do I encode my document to a `Data` object** that I can return from the first method and then decode in the `read(from:ofType:)` method when needed?

The `Codable` protocol and `NSKeyedArchiver` seem to be key components to achieve this. But when I try to encode the attributed string with it as follows:

```
convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()
    do {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        attributedString = values.decode(NSAttributedString.Type, forKey: .attributedString)
    } catch {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I get the compiler error:

> No 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type `NSAttributedString`

It seems like `NSAttributedString` doesn't support encoding/decoding but according to the documentation, it conforms to `NSSecureCoding` which inherits from `NSCoding`.

**How can I encode the whole document with all its properties**, including the attributed string?

(Is there a simpler way than using `NSKeyedArchiver`?)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124396/how-to-make-nsattributedstring-codable-compliant/54127438#54127438